# Magento Featured products one the homepage disappered suddenly!

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I made a new category as "Stock Clearance" and after completing it, when I refreshed my home page my featured products were not showing anymore, Just the title was there, rest blank. Anyone know any fix ? Please check the screenshot below.

[image]

In the above screenshot, that is my homepage, where featured products use to display in each section like new arrivals, new with tag, etc. But suddenly it disappeared. Please if anyone knows any solution, let me know.

Comment: we would need a lot more information to help you

Comment: Sorry @PaddyD. I have attached Screenshot. Please check.

Comment: Have you reindexed?

Comment: Yes I tried doing that too, but didn't work

Comment: you will have to look at the code to see what its actually calling for thoses sections.  It might be calling them in some weird way ( instead of just the category number) and by adding a new category has broken it.  Have you tried just deleting the new category?

Comment: It worked, after deleting the category.